# Is it possible to pull JS variable values from Inspector-like programs? Why/Why not

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a brief why/why not on if it is possible to get Javascript variable's value during run time.

All of my files are stored server side within a .NET MVC Application. On load my `var`'s are all empty, but my Controller will populate them with AJAX during user interactions. **During those actions, can my variable values be seen?**

Please keep answers within the realms of protecting my `var`s from the "average user", not some hacking expert.

Comment: What are you even asking? If your variables are global, they are available to everyone everywhere all the time. Even if they aren't, JS runs on the client and they are still available everywhere to everyone.

Comment: So anyone can see the variable values?

Comment: Of course. Anyone can add a breakpoint in the script, pause execution, and inspect everything in scope.

Comment: I see.. (new to this stuff). So in your opinion, if I have to make secure data calls, should I move all of that into the Controller/Service layers?

Comment: @Austin correct. you should never do something clientside if the end user shouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: "In your opinion" is never going to result in a valid SO question.

Comment: Anything stored on the client can be seen by the user, _period_.  There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: `(function() {window.console&&console.log(window)})()` and F12 would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code run client side is not safe. Not your variables, not your algorithms.

Javascript is client side.

This doesn't mean that any server side code is secure.